# Edit ResourceDictionary from an external assembly

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I've been searching around if it is possible for an assembly to change the ResourceDictionary values from another assembly at runtime. So far I've found nothing.
Here´s the deal. I have a UserControl that will work independently so it can be fit into different projects. My UserControl has its own Resources.xaml (Compiled as Resources).
I have a second assembly that it used as a setup tool for this user control. It basically just reads the UserControl Resources.xaml (which is working great) and then replaces the values of the Resources.Xaml. Trouble is, I cannot change the resource values.

Here's the code I use on my setup tool to read the ResourceDictionary:

```
    <Window.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Control;component/Configuration/Resources.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
     </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
```

To change this values I've tried something like:

```
this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.First()["IsZoomable"] = false;
```

It does recognize the resources but it wont change it. Is it even possible to change the values of the dictionary of another assembly at runtime or will I need to create an external dictionary that can be acessed by both assemblies?

**EDIT:**

- The user control contains the Resources.xaml. I've defined the Resources in this control like this:

  ```
  <UserControl.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary Source="Configuration/Resources.xaml"/>
  </UserControl.Resources>
  ```
- The setup tool can acess this resources but I'm not able to change them. When I do, the user control still reads the old values. Resources are defined in the setup tool like so:

  ```
  <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Control;component/Configuration/Resources.xaml"/>
  </Window.Resources>
  ```

Comment: When you say "wont change it", do you mean it throws an error, or the change just never manifests? If it throws then your resource is probably frozen, if it doesn't manifest then use DynamicResource rather than StaticResource.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the comment. There is no error being thrown. The changes just never manifest. Let me give a try with DynamicResource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change the value of a resource at runtime.
Since you have merged the dictionary, you can change the value like this:

```
this.Resources["IsZoomable"]=false;
```

Make sure that the resource key matches the actual key.
If you have merged the dictionary in app.xaml, then you can use:

```
Application.current.Resources["IsZoomable"]=false;
```

Comment: I've done that and still no changes. In the setup tool I change some values on the ResourceDictionary. I load the UC again and the values are the same as before. I will edit the post with the definitions of my Resources on each project.

Comment: I believe you should check whether you are using the resource as static/dynamic inside the style defined for the usercontrol. because, if you are using it as StaticResouce, even when the value gets changed behind the scenes, it will never be updated for the usercontrol.So, in that case you can use it as DynamicResource so that the changed value gets reflected to the usercontrol.